# Displaying conditional excel data based on userInput React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, excel, react-hooks

I have an excel file (is quite large) as follows:

```
       Region            Country         City
North America      United States     Kentucky
North America      United States     New York
... All cities in US
North America             Canada      Alberta
... All cities in Canada
       Europe             France         Nice
... All cities in France
```

I basically want to convert this to a front-end form. So I would have 3 inputs (one for region, one for country, and one for city). Now, I would like a way where if a user selects North America as a region, I only allow them to select countries within North America, and when a user selects a country, only show them cities within a country.

My current approach to tackle countries within a region is quite simple since there are not many regions:

Main Function - content

```
function content(){
  const [regionValue, setRegionValue] = React.useState();
  const [countryValue, setCountryValue] = React.useState();
  const [cityValue, setCityValue] = React.useState();

  ...Render components
  <RegionSelect regionValue={regionValue} setRegionValue={setRegionValue}></RegionSelect>
  <CountrySelect countryValue={countryValue} setCountryValue={setCountryValue} regionValue={regionValue}></CountrySelect>
}
```

Function for Region:

```
export const REGIONS = [
    { label: 'North America', value: 'North America' },
    { label: 'South America', value: 'South America' },
    { label: 'Europe', value: 'Europe' }
    ...
];

function RegionSelect(props){
  return (
      <Select options = {REGIONS} value = props.regionValue onChange = props.setRegionValue /> //My custom component which just allows user to select and changes the value accordingly
  )

}
```

Function for Country:

```
const NA_COUNTRIES = [
   { label: 'Canada', value: 'Canada' },
   { label: 'United States', value: 'United States' },
   { label: 'Mexico', value: 'Mexico' }
]

const SA_COUNTRIES =....

function CountrySelect(props){
   //since I passed in region to props, I can do an if condition to fill select statement with refined options: 

   if (props.regionValue == 'North America'){
       <Select options = {NA_COUNTRIES} value = props.countryValue onChange = props.setCountryValue />
   }
   else if..... #Else if statements for every region to display other options

}
```

Now the countries are quite easy since there aren't many regions but the cities is where it becomes a bit more difficult and tedious. Is it possible for me to do this a better way (maybe by directly reading a csv file in react and doing a match/join)?

Comment: You export the excel to CSV, find an online service for CSV to JSON and then you save each country's cities as a json file. Which can be imported in any `js/ts` file, like any other array. [Proof of concept](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-architecture-773luc?file=/src/App.js),